# Use multiple keywords in \ printbibliography to filter the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, keywords

Is there a way to filter `\printbibliography` using multiple keywords that are present in the `.bib` file entries ?

For exemple, I'd like the command `\printbibliography[keyword={key_1,key_2,key_3}]` to print ONLY the entries that combines the keywords like `key_1 AND key_2 AND key_3`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32851/15925 help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
\printbibliography[keyword={key_1}, keyword={key_2}, keyword={key_3}]
```

And for omitting those specific keywords the syntax is:

```
\printbibliography[notkeyword={key_1}, notkeyword={key_2}, notkeyword={key_3}]
```

Same works with `category` and `notcategory`.

Comment: Are you sure? In the version on my system here (2.8) you can "stack" `notkeyword` but you can't stack `keyword` and you need to define a filter for that. I haven't got 2.9 to test, but there's nothing in the release notes about it.

Comment: Why shouldn't that work? See manual, 3.6.2 The Bibliography. I'm using bilatex v2.8a / biber v1.8

Comment: You are quite right, and I was quite wrong.

Comment: this works like `AND`. How would you combine `keyword` with `OR`?

Comment: The syntax for OR is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367083/use-multiple-keywords-or-in-printbibliography-to-filter-the-bibliography