# Use multiple keywords (OR) in \ printbibliography to filter the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, keywords, filter

Similarly, but slightly different from [Use multiple keywords in \ printbibliography to filter the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183243/use-multiple-keywords-in-printbibliography-to-filter-the-bibliography) I wonder:

Is there a way to filter `\printbibliography` using multiple keywords that are present in the `.bib` file entries ?

For exemple, I'd like the command `\printbibliography[keyword={key_1,key_2,key_3}]` to print entries that combines at least one of the keywords from the set `key_1` AND/OR `key_2` AND/OR `key_3`.

Comment: try `\printbibliography[keyword=key_1,keyword=key_2,...]`

Comment: thanks @Herbert. As the linked question/answer specifies: the syntax you suggest is used for AND (i.e. print ONLY entries that include all keys).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Biblatex supplied a filter that works:

```
\defbibfilter{example}{%
    keyword=key_1 or keyword=key_2 or keyword=key_3
}

\printbibliography[filter=example, title={References}]
```

---

#### Note

You **can break lines** in `\defbibfilter` like so:

```
\defbibfilter{example}{% 
    keyword=key_1      %  <---- This will work fine
    or keyword=key_2
    or keyword=key_3
}
```

You **can NOT use spaces** in `\defbibfilter` like so:

```
\defbibfilter{example}{% 
    keyword = key_1      %  <---- This will NOT work
    or keyword=key_2
    or keyword=key_3
}
```

Also, `\defbibfilter` doesn't need to be in preamble.